# Subtracting Dates ORA01847

Tags: oracle

I am a newbie to Oracle. I have been looking at the examples how to subtract between two days with to_Date. 
However, every time I run this with to_date logic 
**`SELECT (to_date((SELECT PAYMENT_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID =3) - to_date((SELECT INVOICE_DUE_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID= 3)))) FROM DUAL;`**  I ended up getting this error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Payment Date is : 15-SEP-17 Invoice Due Date is: 24-JUN-17

Is there a simple way to calculate the difference in days between two columns?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to convert with by using `to_date` without formatting like `'dd.mm.rrrr'`. i.e. omit `to_date` clauses. Substracting dates yield a number ( assuming both column PAYMENT_DATE, INVOICE_DUE_DATE are in `date` type )

```
SELECT (SELECT PAYMENT_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID =3) - (SELECT INVOICE_DUE_DATE FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID= 3) INTO v_day FROM DUAL;
```

where v_day is a number. By the way, it's better to use in this way:

```
SELECT ( PAYMENT_DATE - INVOICE_DUE_DATE ) INTO v_day FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_ID =3
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was just making it harder for myself without noticing.